# Way to hide columns in SSRS report based on their comparison

Tags: reporting-services

Situation is like that: I'm making report where I need to hide columns based on their equality between each other.
For example, we have columns ID, A, B, C, D, SUM, etc. All of them take info from one dataset.
I want to hide columns A and B if all of their values equals to each other pair to pair. I mean, if we have this:

```
A|B
1|1
2|2
3|3
```

Then we don't need to show both this columns. If we have something like this:

```
A|B
1|1
2|22
3|3
```

Then we should show them. I've went to column visibility based on expression and tried at first with

```
Iif(Fields!A.Value = Fields!B.Value,true,false)
```

But it worked only if first row id different. In cases like the second here (where we have 2|22 only in second row) it didn't worked. Then I've tried to play with lookup functions:

```
=Iif(Lookup(Fields!A,Fields!B,"1","MainTables") = "1",true,false)
```

That didn't work either. With LookUpSet it throws error before you preview the report, with just LookUp it throws error at execution. What should I put in visibility expression to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to hide the column if the values of columns A and B in ALL rows are identical then you could add a calculated column to your dataset that compares the values on each row and returns a 1 if they do not match. You can then sum this field and if the sum of this field is zero then you can hide the column(s).

Step 1. Edit your dataset adding a new calculated column

In this example I called this `ABMatch` and used this expression

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value=Fields!B.Value,0,1)
```

Then I set the column visibility to base based on an expression, using the following expression.

```
=SUM(Fields!ABMatch.Value) = 0
```

So, if any row is present that contains non-matching values that will return a `1`. When we sum the values, if the result is > 1 then we want to show the column. As the column visibility is actually the `Hidden` property we want to hide it when the sum of the calculated column is zero. In this case the expression will return `True`, hence the column will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I've actually never thought about using calculated fields.